# matrix differentiation of the first order involving differentiation of inverse of matrix by itself

Tags: matrices, derivatives, vectors, matrix-calculus

can some one provide  proof of this differentiation 
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial a'Xb}{\partial X}=ab'
\end{equation}
where $a'$ is transpose of matrix  $a$

Comment: This is unclear. What are a,b,X?

Comment: $a$ is a matrix or vector? I think that is the derivative of a quadratic form.

Answer (score 2):

If you write the function in terms of the [Frobenius Inner Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Frobenius_product), then finding the differential and gradient is simple.
$$\eqalign{
 f &= a^TXb \cr &= ab^T : X \cr\cr
df &= ab^T:dX \cr\cr
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X} &= ab^T \cr 
}$$